# jmock - mocking a method with long[] as input and with(any())

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, jmock

I have a question related to jmock library. I am trying to mock a method that has a parameter of `long[]` and `with(any())`. Is there a direct way to do that?

```
public class A
{
 public void Method_A(long[]  a)
 {
  //Do Somthing. need to mocking 
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you've encountered? Sample code will help.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find a way to do it. I cannot treat it as an object since it doesn't have a '.class' data member. And I cannot treat it as a primitive type as well since the with(equalTo()) isn't available for arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Just use `any(long[].class)`.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason Netbeans shows that .class is not available for long[]. You are right, thanks.